# Link error with Qt5 webkit

Tags: qt-creator, qt5

I want to make a browser in qt5 using qtwebkit but I found some error when I get download my site. I don't know the reason. I added the webkit library, and call it in `mainwindow.h`:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWebKit/QtWebKit>

namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
     public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
     private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_4_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui; };

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->webView->back();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ui->webView->forward();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    ui->webView->reload();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    ui->webView->load("http://" + ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

**and this when i called library**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-10-31T07:39:06
#
#-------------------------------------------------
QT       += core gui QT       += webkit
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = mozilabrwser TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I tried to change the name of webkit but I still get this error:

```
D:\ubunto\QT5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\mozilabrwser\mainwindow.cpp:19: error:
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8QWebView4backEv'
```

Comment: D:\ubunto\QT5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\mozilabrwser\mainwindow.cpp:19: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8QWebView4backEv'

Comment: this is all project
http://www.4shared.com/rar/xpR2f64K/Browser_project.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QT += core gui QT += webkit
```

is wrong. You seem to be using Qt 5, and **in Qt 5 the correct module is `webkitwidgets`**. 2nd issue is format, you seem to have two lines concatenated. So this should work:

```
QT += core gui
QT += webkitwidgets
```

Note: If you need to have the program compile with both Qt4 and Qt5, then you need to use conditional, adding `webkit` for Qt4, `webkitwidgets` for Qt5. But this is probably not a concern for a hobby project, no point clutteirng the `.pro` file with that stuff until you actually need it (you will also need some source changes and `#ifdef` stuff in code if you want to support both, so don't go there unless it is an important requirement).

---

Same two lines concatenated issue seems to be also in line `TARGET = mozilabrwser TEMPLATE = app`.

Comment: not this :( i still found this error
D:\ubunto\QT5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\mozilabrwser\mainwindow.cpp:19: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8QWebView4backEv'